# How to derive the formula to compute an integer window number for given window width and overlap fraction (example given)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, arithmetic, closed-form, integers

I have a task of computing the window number for some  time-dependent signals with overlapping. I have broken down the task to a purely **mathematical (*arithmetic/algebra*) problem** and provide an illustrative example here to aid thinking.

We are given a fixed window length $l_\text{w}$ in seconds, and an overlap fraction $x$.  The windows span `t_start` to `t_finish` (t_start is inclusive and t_finish is exclusive), i.e. the interval is $[t_\text{start}, t_\text{finish})$. The question is, *given a time $t_k$, what is the general mathematical formula that computes the earliest window $N_k \in \mathbb{N}$ that includes $t_k$?*  The formula takes two parameters $l_\text{w}$ and $x$.

If that was too abstract, here is a simple example. Consider $l_\text{w} = 0.4 s$. That is the first window $N_1$ spans $[0,0.4)$. The overlap factor is given to be $x=0.4$ which implies an overlap duration of $x\cdot l_\text{w} = 0.16 s$. 
This means that the next window $N_2$ spans $[0.16,0.56)$ and so on *ad infinitum*.

The table below can then be visualised (and has no ending point). Now, given any time-point $t_k$, what is the most general formula that predicts the window $N_k$ in which it belongs? eg. if $t_k = 1.40$, the formula should predict $N_k$ = 7. if $t_k = 0.96$ it should predict $N_k=5$ and so on.

```
| t_start    | t_finish    | N(window no) |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 0          |       0.40  |     1        |
| 0.16       |       0.56  |     2        |
| 0.40       |       0.80  |     3        |
| 0.56       |       0.96  |     4        |
| 0.80       |       1.20  |     5        |
| 0.96       |       1.36  |     6        |
| 1.20       |       1.60  |     7        |
| 1.36       |       1.76  |     8        |
| 1.60       |       2.00  |     9        |
| 1.76       |       2.16  |    10        |
| 2.00       |       2.40  |    11        |
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by considering only the odd numbered windows.  Every time is in one of these and time $t$ is in window $n=2\lfloor \frac t{0.4} \rfloor+1$.  Now compute how far you are into the window as $\Delta t=t-0.4n$.  If $\Delta t \lt 0.16$ you are in the previous window as well, so subtract $1$.

For the general case, $n=2\lfloor \frac t{l_w} \rfloor+1, \Delta t=t-l_wn$.  If $\Delta t \lt xl_w$ you are in the previous window as well, so subtract $1$.

Comment: That formula is not general. In particular, it works only for this table. If you change $t_\text{w}$ or $x$, it won't work. I am looking for a general formula. The table was just an example of one case

Comment: You can change $0.4$ to $l_w$ and $0.16$ to $xl_w$ and it works fine.  It does depend on the structure of the overlap that you have defined, that every other window starts at a multiple of $l_w$.  I have put that in

Comment: My point is that I already tried your formula before posting here. For a completely different case, say $l_w = 0.72$ and $x=0.35$, will it work? I think my table is not generic enough. I shall change it tomorrow.

Comment: I believe it will.  Do you have an example that says otherwise?  Maybe I have not understood correctly how the overlap works.  Would the start times then be $0,0.252,0.72,0.972,1.44,1.692,2.16$?

Comment: I think my post was wrong. Sorry for wasting your time. I shall revise it soon